# How to write the type of a object with string key and specific object type for value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
export type Distributions = {
    [index: string]: {
        distributions: Array<number>,
        histogramUpperLimit: number,
        nonZeroUser: number,
        percentiles: Array<number>
    }
};

let test: Distributions = {
    "thisIsAID": {
        distributions: 1238
    }
};
```

It should throw errors but it doesn't, what I wrote it incorrect?

Comment: [Error for me...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20type%20Distributions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20distributions%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20histogramUpperLimit%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%3A%20Distributions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22thisIsAID%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20distributions%3A%201238%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: I will try to upgrade typescript. There is not red underline in PHPStorm

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's bug in older version of TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Are you sure your phpStorm is using TypeScript compiler to do their checking? You need to configure it.